# Entity framework Problems

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have this problem:

have two entyties with one to one relationship, boot of them has the same Id Column name

```
    Document_head                sales_Order 
+-----------------+         +------------------+
+ DocumentId      +         + DocumentId       +
+ Person          + 1-----1 + OrderDate        +
+ Status          +         + Purchaser        +
+ ...             +         + ...              +
+ ----------------+         +------------------+
```

Here is the entity definition

```
public partial class Document_head
{

    public Document_head()
    {
       // Other 
    }
    [Key]
    public string DocumentId {get;set;}
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public int status {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("DocumentId")]
    public virtual sales_Order sales_Order { get; set; }
}


public partial class sales_order
{
    public sales_order()
    {
        //Other
    }
    [Key]
    public string DocumentId  { get; set; }

    public virtual Document_head Document_head { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the context

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet Document_head Document_head{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<sales_order> sales_order{ get; set; }

    modelBuilder.Entity<Document_head>()
        .HasOptional(p => p.sales_order).WithRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<sales_order>()
        .HasRequired(p => p.Document_head).WithOptional();
}
```

The problem is when run the MVC3 application.

it say:

> The Column Name "Document_Head_DocumentId" is not valid.

I'm spending many time with this situation, if somebody could help me with this .. would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the configuration as follows. You need only single configuration line and that should include both navigational fields.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet Document_head Document_head{ get; set; }
    public DbSet sales_order{ get; set; }

    modelBuilder.Entity‹sales_order›().HasRequired(p => p.Document_head)
         .WithOptional(p => p.sales_order);
}
```

Comment: +1 to this answer, I highly recommend you to use fluent api rather than data annotations, since the former has much more capabilities.

Comment: Very tks for  your quick answer..... I did the changes .. but the problem persists... why:  public DbSet sales_order{ get; set; } instead public DbSet &lt;sales_order&gt; sales_order{ get; set; }

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez Its not clear what you have put on comment. Can you update your question

Comment: sorry.. omit that comment... The *proble persists. i'm checking another relations. Very very tks for your help.

Comment: The problem was with another entity. A relationsihip many-to-many it was solved. TKS AGAIN